# Validating a partial message from a hash

Tags: hash

Let's say I have 3 items `(A, B, C)`. Is there some sort of hash algorithm such that if I send `(A, B, C)` to another person, they can give me back the same hash and the same items or a subset of those items (for example `(A, C)`), and I can validate that they didn't give me extra/invalid items (for example `(A, D)`)?

I apologize in advance for my lack of mathematical background.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Can you give more context?

Comment: Could you explain the problem with more clarity?

Comment: Does a Merkle tree possibly do what you want? If you want to validate a subset then you need the entire tree of hashes. And if you want to have it order independent then you can simply order the elements prior to hashing.

Comment: There do seem to be extra requirements missing as the current description seems to be solvable by associating a token with each element (e.g. its hash) and then checking that only previously known tokens are returned.